# Using Matlab regexp on a cell array to return specific filenames

Tags: arrays, regex, matlab, cell

I have a folder in which there are many files and I want to create a matrix that holds filenames with a specific pattern. For example: The folder contains files with names starting with a subject number (e.g. 03T1A.xxx.nii, 03T1A.yyy.nii) as well as filenames with specific patterns in the middle (e.g. 03T1A.c100.nii, 03T1A.c200.nii, 03T1A.c300.nii). In this specific case I am looking to extract all the filenames with the pattern c1 and c2 in the middle (e.g. 03T1A.c100.nii and 03T1A.c200.nii but not 03T1A.c300.nii).

To this point I have used the following code to create a pattern matching variable in *'pattern'* which I would like to apply to the cell array of filenames I have extracted into the variable *'all_files'* via the **dir** call.

```
func_path = char(strcat(input_dir, '/', subs(files), '/Func'));
pattern = 'c[12]*.nii'
all_files = dir(func_path); 
all_files = {all_files.name};
```

I'd like to use (read. practice) **regexp** and doing it with string input seems easy but I am 100% stumped as to how to do it with cell input.
I started trying to do something like this:

```
files = all_files(cellfun(@(x)regexp(x, pattern));
```

But it doesn't work, obviously. Could someone help me figure out what to do here if my ultimate goal is to get a matrix output with just the relevant filenames? I've been searching MATLAB answers and other Stack Overflow posts but part of my problem is I don't understand what's happening in their code snippets. I took the above line (or at the least the beginning of it) from another post but I don't know what, for example, 'x' is (an output variable?) or what's going on in the larger command such as

```
fin = cellfun(@(x)regexp(x, '\.', 'split'), res, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Which I found in another thread.
So basically, can someone help me figure out a command that will work while explaining it to me?

Comment: `regexp` works natively on cell arrays, there is no need to use `cellfun`. See also: [`Regex 101`](https://regex101.com/) as a playground for building [the expression](https://regex101.com/r/srr2Pg/1).

Comment: I had originally tried to use the command:
x = regexp(all_files, pattern, 'match')
But it returns an empty cell array of the same size as 'all_files.'

Comment: Then your `pattern` didn't match anything.

Comment: Holy crap, you were absolutely right.
If I had files c1004.EXAMPLE.nii and c2004.EXAMPLE.nii, for some reason the pattern 'c[12]*.nii' returns nothing but the pattern 'c[12]' returns both correctly. Is there any reason why this is?

Comment: @chainhomelow Yes, because `c[12]*.nii` will only match a "c" followed by *only* 1's and 2's before the `.nii`. You would need `c[12].*\.nii` so that you can match everything else in the string between `c1` or `c2` and the extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of recommendations for doing this sort of thing

1. Do not use `strcat` and `'/'` characters to construct file paths. [`strcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) trims whitespace from all inputs prior to concatenation (filenames may have actual leading or trailing whitespace) and also rather than hard-coding a file path separator such as `'/'` , use [`filesep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html) or better yet use [`fullfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) to construct the path to ensure that it will work on various platforms without problems.

   ```
   func_path = fullfile(input_dir, subs(files), 'Func');
   ```
2. `regexp` works *directly* on cell arrays therefore you can simply do:

   ```
   all_files = dir(func_path); 

   % Search for the pattern in all filenames
   matches = regexp({all_files.name}, pattern);

   % Get the filenames of those that matched
   all_files = {all_files(~cellfun('isempty', matches)).name};
   ```
3. Your pattern isn't matching any files because it currently would match only strings that contain a "c" with *only* zero or more 1's or 2's before the file extension. Instead, you'll want to use `.*` to match anything *between* the "c1" or "c2" and the filename. Also you'll want to *not* use a `*` after `[12]` since that will actually match `c3` since that has zero 1's or 2's.  Also you'll want to escape the `.` in `.nii` so that it's not treated like a wildcard. For your pattern I would use something like

   ```
   pattern = 'c[12].*\.nii';
   ```
4. If you really don't want to work with regular expressions, you could avoid all of this by simply [using wildcards in your `dir` call](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html#buscvwz-1)

   ```
   c1_files = dir(fullfile(func_path, '*c1*.nii'));
   c2_files = dir(fullfile(func_path, '*c2*.nii'));
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much, this does the trick for sure. I was looking at the regexp usage and yeah the wildcard thing threw me off. Apparently you can also use 'c[12]\S*nii' as well but the syntax change threw me.

The strcat comment was very helpful as well, and the 'isempty' line works for completeness to give me exactly the new array I need. Really appreciate it.